# SImple XML Framework: XPath matching based on attribute value

Tags: java, xml, xpath, simple-framework

Given XML like this:

```
...
<Sport SportId="1">
    <Name language="en">Soccer</Name>
    <Name language="fi">Jalkapallo</Name>       
     ...    
</Sport>
...
```

How can I, using the [Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/), read the two values into fields in a Java class? (The `<Sport>` element is already correctly mapped to the corresponding class.)

```
public class Sport {    
    ...
    String nameEn;
    String nameFi;
    ...
}
```

I've tried approaches like:

```
@Element(name = "Name")
@Path("Name[@language='en']")
String nameEn;
```

But the parsing fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.simpleframework.xml.core.PathException: 
  Invalid index for path '[@language='en']' in field 'nameEn'
```

Also, omitting `@Element` like this:

```
@Path("Name[@language='en']")
String nameEn;
```

...parsing doesn't crash, but `nameEn` value stays null.

I'd like the matching to be based on the **language attribute** (instead of ordering), but I'm wondering if that's possible (maybe XPath support in Simple Framework is limited?).

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @mikehc, not directly, if I recall right. :/ I think I used some workaround such as relying on the order of the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the text of the element explicitly? i.e. `Name[@language='en']/text()`

Your Xpath is selecting the *element*, not the *text* of the element, which can cause some XML engines to choke.

Comment: Well, I tried `@Element(name = "Name")` and `@Path("Name[@language='en']/text()")`, which produces `org.simpleframework.xml.core.PathException: Invalid index for path 'Name[@language='en']/text()' in field 'nameEn'`. And some other variations too, but no luck.